Exception: Service Spreadsheets timed out while accessing document with id : error message while collecting data from another spreadsheet
While I am running manually a script to automatically send emails based on data in other tabs, I am getting this message very regularly, and it seem it happens between the 2 console.log in the code below.
I tried to add "SpreadsheetApp.flush()" as recommended in other threads.
Can you please help?
Here is the code :
function Email(linenumber) {
  // Fonction qui email la donnée de la ligne linenumber de l'onglet d'Email

  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();


  // Obtenir les informations depuis l'onglet "Email" sur le travail à mener
  var emailSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Email");
  var emailData = emailSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Récupère le header de l'onglet Email
  headsEmailData = emailData[0];

  // Récupère les indexs des colonnes de l'onglet Email
  var idxObjectEmail = headsEmailData.indexOf("objectEmail");
  var idxSheetUrl = headsEmailData.indexOf("sheetUrl");
  var idxTablesEmail = headsEmailData.indexOf("tablesEmail");
  var idxAttachmentsEmail = headsEmailData.indexOf("attachmentsEmail");
  var idxAttachmentsType = headsEmailData.indexOf("attachmentsType");
  var idxBodyEmail = headsEmailData.indexOf("bodyEmail");
  var idxRecipientsEmail = headsEmailData.indexOf("recipientsEmail");
  var idxNoreplyEmail = headsEmailData.indexOf("noreplyEmail");
  var idxLastEmailDate = headsEmailData.indexOf("lastEmailDate");
  var idxLastEmailLength = headsEmailData.indexOf("lastEmailLength");
  var idxStartHour = headsEmailData.indexOf("startHour");
  var idxEndHour = headsEmailData.indexOf("endHour");
  var idxReplyTo = headsEmailData.indexOf("replyTo");



  // Parcourir la ligne linenumber ligne dans l'onglet "Email"
  var objectEmail = emailData[linenumber][idxObjectEmail];
  var sheetUrl = emailData[linenumber][idxSheetUrl];
  var attachmentsType = emailData[linenumber][idxAttachmentsType];
  var bodyEmail = emailData[linenumber][idxBodyEmail];
  var recipientsEmail = emailData[linenumber][idxRecipientsEmail];
  var noreplyEmail = emailData[linenumber][idxNoreplyEmail];
  var attachmentsEmail = emailData[linenumber][idxAttachmentsEmail].split(",");
  var tablesEmail = emailData[linenumber][idxTablesEmail].split(",");
  var replyTo = emailData[linenumber][idxReplyTo];

  // Extraire l'ID de la Google Sheet à partir du lien
  var sourceSpreadsheetId = extractSpreadsheetId(sheetUrl);
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetId);

  // Initialize email body
  var bodyEmail = bodyEmail + "<br>";

  
  //Ajout de emailOptions : Une variable emailOptions est créée pour stocker les options de l'email, avec htmlBody initialisé. Condition if pour noreplyEmail : Si noreplyEmail est égal à "TRUE" (indépendamment de la casse), noReply est ajouté à emailOptions. Appel de GmailApp.sendEmail : La fonction est appelée avec emailOptions comme argument.

  var emailOptions = { htmlBody: bodyEmail, attachments: [] };

  // Mise en place du no reply
  if (noreplyEmail.toString().toUpperCase() === "TRUE") {
    emailOptions.noReply = true;
  }

  if (replyTo) {
    emailOptions.replyTo = replyTo;
  }

  // ajout des PJ
  if (attachmentsEmail!=''){
    for (var j = 0; j < attachmentsEmail.length; j++) {
    var fileSheetName = attachmentsEmail[j].trim();
    var fileSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(fileSheetName);

    // Vérifie la présence de l'onglet source
    if(fileSheet==null){
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Un onglet de attachmentsEmail n'est pas présent dans le fichier source : "+fileSheet, SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
    return;
    }
    else {
        //Vérifie la présence de l'onglet
        var sheetTemp = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(fileSheetName+"_temp");
        if (!sheetTemp) {
          sheetTemp=sourceSpreadsheet.insertSheet(fileSheetName+"_temp");        
        }
console.log(fileSheetName+" vérification de la présence de l'onglet");
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        var totalRows = fileSheet.getLastRow();
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        var totalCols = fileSheet.getLastColumn();
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        var sourceRange = fileSheet.getRange(1,1,totalRows,totalCols);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
console.log(fileSheetName+" range récupéré");
        var targetRange = sheetTemp.getRange(1,1);
        sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange);
        sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange,SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_COLUMN_WIDTHS,false);
        sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange,SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+sourceSpreadsheetId+"/export"+"?format=xlsx"+"&gid="+sheetTemp.getSheetId();                                      
        var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
        var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob().setName(fileSheetName+".xlsx");
        emailOptions.at​​tachments.push(blob);
        sourceSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheetTemp);
    }
    }
  }


  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipientsEmail, objectEmail, "", emailOptions);

  }
}

I'm trying to access another spreadsheet to collect data, then to send it by email.
In the process of accessing the other doc, I get this unexpected message error as in the title : Exception: Service Spreadsheets timed out while accessing document with id

The declaration of extractSpreadsheetId is missing.

Several reasons might cause the "Spreadsheet Service timeout while accessing ... " error, some of which are not actionable by end-users. First, you should review how complex and how much time it takes to open and finish the recalculation. If the spreadsheet is simple and takes up to a few seconds to recalculate, try creating a copy of the spreadsheet and accessing the copy instead of the original.
If that doesn't work or the spreadsheet is complex and takes more than a few seconds to recalculate, you might have to look at previous questions about the same error to look for other troubleshooting tips.

It looks like you misunderstood the purpose of SpreadsheetApp.flush() as the code includes this statement too many times. All except the last one don't make sense.
Below is the question code with the unnecessary  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); turned into comments. I added a comment above, which is the only one that is required.
function Email(linenumber) {
  // Fonction qui email la donnée de la ligne linenumber de l'onglet d'Email

  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();


  // Obtenir les informations depuis l'onglet "Email" sur le travail à mener
  var emailSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Email");
  var emailData = emailSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Récupère le header de l'onglet Email
  headsEmailData = emailData[0];

  // Récupère les indexs des colonnes de l'onglet Email
  var idxObjectEmail = headsEmailData.indexOf("objectEmail");
  var idxSheetUrl = headsEmailData.indexOf("sheetUrl");
  var idxTablesEmail = headsEmailData.indexOf("tablesEmail");
  var idxAttachmentsEmail = headsEmailData.indexOf("attachmentsEmail");
  var idxAttachmentsType = headsEmailData.indexOf("attachmentsType");
  var idxBodyEmail = headsEmailData.indexOf("bodyEmail");
  var idxRecipientsEmail = headsEmailData.indexOf("recipientsEmail");
  var idxNoreplyEmail = headsEmailData.indexOf("noreplyEmail");
  var idxLastEmailDate = headsEmailData.indexOf("lastEmailDate");
  var idxLastEmailLength = headsEmailData.indexOf("lastEmailLength");
  var idxStartHour = headsEmailData.indexOf("startHour");
  var idxEndHour = headsEmailData.indexOf("endHour");
  var idxReplyTo = headsEmailData.indexOf("replyTo");



  // Parcourir la ligne linenumber ligne dans l'onglet "Email"
  var objectEmail = emailData[linenumber][idxObjectEmail];
  var sheetUrl = emailData[linenumber][idxSheetUrl];
  var attachmentsType = emailData[linenumber][idxAttachmentsType];
  var bodyEmail = emailData[linenumber][idxBodyEmail];
  var recipientsEmail = emailData[linenumber][idxRecipientsEmail];
  var noreplyEmail = emailData[linenumber][idxNoreplyEmail];
  var attachmentsEmail = emailData[linenumber][idxAttachmentsEmail].split(",");
  var tablesEmail = emailData[linenumber][idxTablesEmail].split(",");
  var replyTo = emailData[linenumber][idxReplyTo];

  // Extraire l'ID de la Google Sheet à partir du lien
  var sourceSpreadsheetId = extractSpreadsheetId(sheetUrl);
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetId);

  // Initialize email body
  var bodyEmail = bodyEmail + "<br>";

  
  //Ajout de emailOptions : Une variable emailOptions est créée pour stocker les options de l'email, avec htmlBody initialisé. Condition if pour noreplyEmail : Si noreplyEmail est égal à "TRUE" (indépendamment de la casse), noReply est ajouté à emailOptions. Appel de GmailApp.sendEmail : La fonction est appelée avec emailOptions comme argument.

  var emailOptions = { htmlBody: bodyEmail, attachments: [] };

  // Mise en place du no reply
  if (noreplyEmail.toString().toUpperCase() === "TRUE") {
    emailOptions.noReply = true;
  }

  if (replyTo) {
    emailOptions.replyTo = replyTo;
  }

  // ajout des PJ
  if (attachmentsEmail!=''){
    for (var j = 0; j < attachmentsEmail.length; j++) {
    var fileSheetName = attachmentsEmail[j].trim();
    var fileSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(fileSheetName);

    // Vérifie la présence de l'onglet source
    if(fileSheet==null){
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Un onglet de attachmentsEmail n'est pas présent dans le fichier source : "+fileSheet, SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
    return;
    }
    else {
        //Vérifie la présence de l'onglet
        var sheetTemp = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(fileSheetName+"_temp");
        if (!sheetTemp) {
          sheetTemp=sourceSpreadsheet.insertSheet(fileSheetName+"_temp");        
        }
console.log(fileSheetName+" vérification de la présence de l'onglet");
        // SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        var totalRows = fileSheet.getLastRow();
        // SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        var totalCols = fileSheet.getLastColumn();
        // SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        var sourceRange = fileSheet.getRange(1,1,totalRows,totalCols);
        // SpreadsheetApp.flush();
console.log(fileSheetName+" range récupéré");
        var targetRange = sheetTemp.getRange(1,1);
        sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange);
        sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange,SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_COLUMN_WIDTHS,false);
        sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange,SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);

        /**
         * This SpreadsheetApp.flush(); is the only one that is required
         */
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+sourceSpreadsheetId+"/export"+"?format=xlsx"+"&gid="+sheetTemp.getSheetId();                                      
        var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
        var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob().setName(fileSheetName+".xlsx");
        emailOptions.at​​tachments.push(blob);
        sourceSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheetTemp);
    }
    }
  }


  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipientsEmail, objectEmail, "", emailOptions);

  }
}


Thanks for the reply!
I inserted the flush according to this solution found in another topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64535334/google-sheet-error-service-spreadsheets-timed-out-while-accessing-document-with
I could indeed create a copy of the source spreadsheet before working on it. What is quite surprising for me is that the source spreadsheet where I collect data is not big and very fast to recalcultate + I get the error message only after 20s of script, I don"t understand why it does not try longer to access the document.
